# `[faq]` magic link does not magically link to the FAQ

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, magic-links

There is a `[faq]` magic link. When you use it, it appears to work, and it gets rendered as `FAQ`. However, despite the fact that it is the `[faq]` magic link, that it gets rendered as `FAQ`, and that it appears to work, because it is rendered as a link … the `[faq]` magic link does not actually magically link to the FAQ, it links to the Tour.

That is mightily confusing, because it is in no way obvious to either the author of the comment or the reader that the link does not actually lead where the author intended.

We already have a magic link for the Tour, namely `[tour]`. If someone wants to link to the Tour, that's the link they would use. If I use the link `[faq]`, I definitely want to link to the FAQ, not the Tour.

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but either way it is confusing and does not match the intent of the comment author.

The `[faq]` magic link should magically link to the FAQ, e.g. to [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/2988) for SO. Not all sites have FAQs, AFAIK, so on sites that don't have a FAQ, the `[faq]` magic link should not exist at all.

Note: I found some prior discussions that explain why `[faq]` should link to the help center, but a) that's not actually what it's doing, and b) is problematic for the same reasons.

Comment: I assume SE doesn't want to maintain a table that holds redirects to a specific post on each site meta. At best it could link to the site meta [meta-tag:FAQ]

Comment: At least on [so] / [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com), the FAQ page is a manually curated list of `[tag:faq]` questions, so your proposal would be close enough. (Actually, the curated list could be linked to and/or kept in the tag wiki for `[tag:faq]`.)

Comment: The magic link is supposed to link to the old `/faq` pages, but those were removed in 2013 and replaced with the help center. The old link now redirects to the tour page. That's why you see that link going there.